# How to wear year, month and date from ISO?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to wear year, month and date from ISO?

From the backend I get a date in ISO format:

```
birthdate: '09-09-1990'
```

Prior to this, when the date came in a date format, I did this:

```
const birthDate = new Date(user.birthdate)
const day = birthDate.getDate().toString()
const month = birthDate.getMonth() + 1
const year = birthDate.getFullYear()
```

Comment: btw, it doesn't look like [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: I suggest you learn about regular expressions and capturing groups. (Also, ISO format has the year first.)

Answer (score 0):

The format that you specified is not an ISO format. However for the format specified, you can directly get year, day and month by splitting. You can try below for such strings. You may see if it help you

```
var str = '09-09-1990'
  var res = str.split("-");
  var day = res[0]
  var month = res[1]
  var year = res[2]
```

Comment: @reactchel Did it help you? Please upvote or accept the answer if it helped you